# Cómo solucionar el error Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 en Spring Tool Suite?

Tags: java, spring-tool-suite, java-build-path

Tengo la version del JDK **jdk-11.0.17**, al ejecutar el comando java -version y javac -version me da esta misma versión.
Al crear un proyecto en Spring Tool Suite (STS) que tengo la versión 4.7.0 RELEASE con la opción Spring Starter Proyect, y pongo la version de java 11, al ejecutar el proyecto me sale el siguiente error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
> at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
> at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
> at projectTestJsonSwift1.Ejemplo33Application.main(Ejemplo33Application.java:11)

como puedo solucionar este error?
si doy click derecho sobre el proyecto, en properties, tengo lo siguiente en Java Build Path

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en Java Compiler

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que tengo que mover para que me deje correr el proyecto?

En el menu-- Window-- Preferences-- Java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como le estás pidiendo compatibilidad con Java8, los artefactos de Spring Boot que incluiste compilados con Java11 no son compatibles. Tienes que poner Java8 en el starter para que todo sea compatible; que la JVM que uses pa compilar sea jdk11, eso es diferente

Comment: a que te refieres en el starter? o sea cuando creas el proyecto? porque ya probe creando un nuevo componente y eligiendo la version de java 8, pero al correr me sale lo mismo

Comment: Me refiero a `con la opción Spring Starter Proyect, y pongo la version de java 11`. Si vas a compilar con compatibilidad a Java8, todas las clases deben compilarse con compatibilidad Java8 o te va a salir este error. Si tienes cosas adicionales que has intentado, ve a [edit] y añade esa información.

Comment: si ya intente cambiando a java 8, pero aun asi me sale ese mismo error, en que otras opciones debo fijarme para ver que todo ese parejo a java 8?